# how to save imageof axes for high resolution in matlab GUI

Tags: matlab, save, export, matlab-guide, axes

I trying save image with  the comand 'getframe' but resolution is very low, so I can not give zoom. for now I'm using the code:

```
[arq,dir] = uiputfile('*.jpg','Output Files');
fileName=fullfile(dir,arq);
f=getframe(handles.axes1);
[x,map]=frame2im(f);
imwrite(x,fileName,'jpg');
```

I need save in jpg and also need save the label (x,y) in graph. How do ? There is another command better than the getframe??

Print is a good command?

Thanks

Comment: Also, here is what the [documentation](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/getframe.html) about `getframe` says: > **Resolution of Captured Frames**
> > The resolution of the framed image depends on the size of the axes in
> pixels when `getframe` is called. As the `getframe` command takes a
> snapshot of the screen, if the axes is small in size (e.g., because
> you have restricted the view to a window within the axes), `getframe`
> captures fewer screen pixels, and the captured image might have poor
> resolution if enlarged for display.

Answer (score 0):

try using something other than jpg, it doesn't scale well. eps is a good choice as it is a vector format.

Answer (score 0):

Try `exportfig` from FEX: [exportfig](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/23629-exportfig)