# how save image with better or specificresolution in gui matlab?

Tags: matlab, export, matlab-figure, matlab-guide, save-as

I trying save image with the command `getframe` but resolution is very low, so I can not give zoom.

For now I'm using the code:

```
[arq,dir] = uiputfile('*.jpg','Output Files');
fileName=fullfile(dir,arq);
f=getframe(handles.axes1);
[x,map]=frame2im(f);
imwrite(x,fileName,'jpg');
```

I need save in JPG and also need save the label (x,y) in graph. How can I do this?

There is another command better than the getframe?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16441181/how-to-save-imageof-axes-for-high-resolution-in-matlab-gui

Comment: Is this a repeat of the http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16441181/how-to-save-imageof-axes-for-high-resolution-in-matlab-gui question? Have you seen all answers there?

Comment: thought about using print command, someone help me?

Comment: See my answer to your first question.